# Multiple Self joins and null values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm certain this is going to be an easy fix but here we are.

I have a table that draws data from a checklist, and I want to build a report based on answers of a few of the questions.

The table is set up like so:

```
list_id | QuestionID | Question   | Answer
   1    |     11     | Supervisor?| Jack
   1    |     12     |  Crew 1?   | Sam
   1    |     13     |  Crew 2?   | Sally
   1    |     14     |  Crew 3?   | NULL
```

There is potentially 'Crew 3?' but it is usually null, same with Crew 2 for that matter. Now I want the Report to look like this:

```
Supervisor | Crew 1 | Crew 2 | Crew 3
```

But when I use left join to self join the table, I only get the results that include all three crew, and leave out all the instances where there is null fields.

My current attempt is:

```
SELECT
      sup.Answer AS 'Sup'
      ,C1.Answer AS '1'
      ,C2.Answer AS '2'
      ,C3.Answer AS '3'
  FROM ChecklistDetail AS sup
  LEFT JOIN ChecklistDetail AS C1 
       ON C1.listID =sup.listID

  LEFT JOIN ChecklistDetail AS C2 
       ON C2.listID =sup.listID

  LEFT JOIN ChecklistDetail AS C3 
       ON C3.listID =sup.listID

  WHERE 
  sup.QuestionID = 11
  AND C1.QuestionID = 12
  AND C2.QuestionID = 13
  AND C3.QuestionID = 14
```

Its probably something obvious but I've hit a bit of a brick wall searching through google and finding a bunch of *pretty close* answers that don't quite work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Oh! My apologies, first post and all that. I'm using SQL-Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question directly, put the question id filters in to the joins...  That way the check is made during the join, rather than after it (when the id may be NULL).

```
  SELECT
      sup.Answer AS 'Sup'
      ,C1.Answer AS '1'
      ,C2.Answer AS '2'
      ,C3.Answer AS '3'
  FROM ChecklistDetail AS sup
  LEFT JOIN ChecklistDetail AS C1 
       ON C1.listID =sup.listID
       AND C1.QuestionID = 12
  LEFT JOIN ChecklistDetail AS C2 
       ON C2.listID =sup.listID
       AND C2.QuestionID = 13
  LEFT JOIN ChecklistDetail AS C3 
       ON C3.listID =sup.listID
       AND C3.QuestionID = 14
  WHERE 
      sup.QuestionID = 11
```

A better way, however, may be conditional aggregation...

```
SELECT
  ListID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN QuestionID = 11 THEN Answer END)   AS 'sup', 
  MAX(CASE WHEN QuestionID = 12 THEN Answer END)   AS '1', 
  MAX(CASE WHEN QuestionID = 13 THEN Answer END)   AS '2', 
  MAX(CASE WHEN QuestionID = 14 THEN Answer END)   AS '3'
FROM
  ChecklistDetail
WHERE
  QuestionID IN (11,12,13,14)
GROUP BY
  ListID
```

Comment: Aaaaannd it was that simple! Thank you so much! I'll have to look into conditional aggregation, but this will certainly work for now.

Comment: @zacwatkins I've added the conditional aggregation SQL now *(also, look in to PIVOT, though I dislike it and prefer conditional aggregation, for my sins)*